# Tkinter problem with text box. How i can fix this?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3 as sql

class main_window:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind= window
        self.wind.geometry('800x500')
        self.wind.resizable(0, 0)
        self.wind.configure(bg= '#1E1E1E')
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        notes_list= tk.Listbox(width= 150, height= 25, bg= '#333333', highlightthickness=0)
        notes_list.pack(padx= 10, pady= 5)

        open_bt= tk.Button(text= 'Open', width= 8, height= 2, bg= '#B0B0B0')
        open_bt.pack(padx= 5, pady= 10, side= 'left')

        new_bt= tk.Button(text= 'New', width= 8, height= 2, bg= '#B0B0B0', command= lambda: new_note(tk.Tk()))
        new_bt.pack(padx= 5, pady= 10, side= 'left')

        delete_bt= tk.Button(text= 'Delete', width= 8, height= 2, bg= '#B0B0B0')
        delete_bt.pack(padx= 5, pady= 10, side= 'left')


class new_note:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind= window
        self.wind.geometry('800x450')
        self.wind.configure(bg= '#1E1E1E')
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        self.title= tk.Entry(self.wind, width= 100, font= ("Comic Sans MS", 10, "bold"), bg= '#333333')
        self.title.pack(padx= 10, pady= 3)

        self.note= tk.Text(self.wind, width= 100, height= 17, bg= '#333333', font= ("Comic Sans MS", 10, "bold"))
        self.note.pack(padx= 10, pady= 5)

        save_bt= tk.Button(self.wind, text= 'Save', width= 8, height= 2, bg= '#B0B0B0', command= self.save)
        save_bt.pack(padx= 5, pady= 10, side= 'left')

        delete_bt= tk.Button(self.wind, text= 'Delete', width= 8, height= 2, bg= '#B0B0B0', command= self.wind.destroy)
        delete_bt.pack(padx= 10, pady= 5, side= 'left')
    
    def save(self):
        db= sql.connect('notas.db')
        curs= db.cursor()
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO tb_notes(name, text) VALUES(?, ?)", self.title.get(), self.note.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
        db.commit()
        db.close()

    

obj_m_window= main_window(tk.Tk())
obj_m_window.wind.mainloop()
```

I want the data to save into the table but when I press the save button, I get this error
`TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: I make a edit. This: curs.execute("INSERT INTO tb_notes(name, text) VALUES(?, ?)", (self.title.get(), self.note.get("1.0",'end-1c')))                                                                                         But now i have this error qlite3.OperationalError: no such table: tb_notes and im sure the name of the table its ok

Comment: try pass your sql values as a list `curs.execute("INSERT INTO tb_notes(name, text) VALUES(?, ?)", [self.title.get(), self.note.get("1.0",'end-1c')])`

Answer (score 1):

**Pass your data as a Tuple**

The `cursor.execute()` function takes two arguments, the SQL statement and the data, in the form of a list or tuple.
Replace the line

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO tb_notes(name, text) VALUES(?, ?)", self.title.get(), self.note.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
```

with

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO tb_notes(name, text) VALUES(?, ?)", (self.title.get(), self.note.get("1.0",'end-1c')))
```

Note that the two pieces of data: `self.title.get()` and `self.note.get("1.0",'end-1c')` are now combined into one single argument.

For a complete explanation of the `sqlite3` module, see this tutorial: [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)